# Should s3 image references be stored in database table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am working on a project where i need to store photo albums for a user. I will have s3 bucket structure as such where i can get the photos for an album.

Wanted to understand if it makes sense to store those photo references in database table? Since s3 itself allows storing some metadata on photos.

Comment: I would recommend storing the key within the bucket, but not a full URI. This allows you to more easily copy/switch buckets.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted so much. It's a valid question and in some cases it does makes sense to store metadata in the S3 file. But creating database tables is definitely the better long-term option per reasons stated in the accepted response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a storage service, not a database.

A photo app would need to be able to perform operations such as:

- List all of a user's photos
- Share photos with other users
- Find photos based on geolocation information
- Find photos by date

All of these activities need a database to help identify photos and their data. In contrast, the metadata capabilities of Amazon S3 only allow data to be stored or retrieved from **one object at a time**. There is no capability, for example, to search for all S3 objects with a particular tag.

**Bottom line:** Use S3 to store objects, but use a database to track objects and their metadata.